# GuessingGame Math.random - Create a guessing game where the c

Tags: java

I am creating an Instantiable Class Guessing Game app where computer comes up with a random number and the user guesses (output winner or loser), however there is something not working on my code, it only returns me Winner if userInput = 0.

I have added a System.out.println as check the random number generated and confirm if the code was working properly.

Could you please help me?

## Guessing Game Class Code

```
public class GuessingGame {

//define variable
    private int randomNum;
    private int userInput;
    private String msg;

    //Constructor method

    public void GuessingGame(){
        randomNum = 0;
        userInput = 0 ;
        msg = "";
    }
    //set method
    public void setRandomNum(double randomNumber){
        this.randomNum = randomNum;
    }
    public void setUserInput(int userInput){
        this.userInput = userInput;
    }

    // compute method
    public void computeMsg() {
        if (randomNum == userInput) {
            msg = "Winner";
        } else {
            msg = "Loser";
        }
    }
        //get method
        public String getMsg(){
            return msg;
        }
    }
```

## Guessing Game App Class Code

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GuessingGameApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declare variables
        int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
        int userInput;
        String msg;

        //declare and create objects
        GuessingGame c;
        c = new GuessingGame();
        System.out.println(randomNum);

        userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a guess"));

        //set
        c.setRandomNum(randomNum);
        c.setUserInput(userInput);

        //compute
        c.computeMsg();

        //get
        msg = c.getMsg();

        //output
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here...

```
public void setRandomNum(double randomNumber) {
    this.randomNum = randomNum;
}
```

You pass in `randomNumber`, but you assign `randomNum` to itself

It should be...

```
public void setRandomNum(double randomNumber) {
    this.randomNum = randomNumber;
}
```